# How to get correct mouse position in Python Qt5?

Tags: python, qt5, pyside6

I'm trying to get correct mouse position in mouseReleaseEvent, but the mouse position I got is wrong.The ev.position() is not relative position on Widget.

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.pad = ChessPad()
        w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        l = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        w.setLayout(l)
        l.addWidget(self.pad)
        self.setCentralWidget(w)
```

```
class ChessPad(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        pad = QtGui.QPixmap(700, 300)
        pad.fill(Qt.white)
        self.setPixmap(pad)        

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, ev):
        
        ev_x = ev.position().x()
        ev_y = ev.position().y()
        print(ev_x, ev_y)
```

Comment: Why do you think `Qt` is reporting the wrong mouse position?

Comment: The position is correct. You're probably *resizing* the window, so the label will be resized along with it, but *not* its pixmap, which by default is always centered. If you want to get the correct position based on the pixmap, you have to map the cursor to the geometry. Otherwise, use the alignment when adding it so that it will not occupy the entire cell of the layout: `l.addWidget(self.pad, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)`.

Answer (score 0):

I get a workaround to solve this issue. I add a label in vboxlayout, the ev.position() will return relative position.

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.pad = ChessPad()

        label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Chess Pad")
        w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        l = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        w.setLayout(l)
        l.addWidget(label)
        l.addWidget(self.pad)
        self.setCentralWidget(w)
```

Comment: It seems a QT bug